# Browser showing an empty page from html

Tags: html, css

My browser is showing a blank page when I open an html file with the following code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Learning CSS</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<p> test </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I originally copy pasted the source code from example.com and then deleted the css, but nothing was showing up, So i made this test, still nothing showing up

Answer (score 3):

The `<style>` tag in the `<head>` is missing its expected matching `</style>`.

Works as expected when adding the closing `</style>` tag.

Note: A helpful method to debug HTML is W3C Validator. If you go here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and copy/paste your code, it will also show the missing `</style>` tag error in its output.

Comment: Sorry which tag is missing? I must be blind i can't see it

Comment: @JoeBlake updated above; I forgot to add the code markup to display the HTML tags as text.

Answer (score 2):

Missing closing `<style>` tag, you have:

```
<style type="text/css">
```

But it should be removed or closed:

```
   <style type="text/css">
   </style>
```

Comment: Ah I see thank you i meant to remove that actually!!